# How to let a roomate know that their speakerphone is loud and I can hear it?

Tags: roommates

I have a roommate who is on his phone a lot (he works from home over the phone). His phone is always on speakerphone at quite a loud volume. When his door will be closed and my door is closed and I'm also around a corner in my room, I can still hear everything he is doing on his phone. This includes watching videos or listening to music or talking about (potentially) sensitive information with a client.

This isn't a problem if no one else is home, but I get annoyed by it pretty easy. If I'm just trying to have a quiet moment reading a book, I can put on headphones to block the sound but get a little miffed that I have to do this. The bigger problem is when he is on a call or listening to music when I am trying to sleep, which happens less frequently.

I've thought about how to bring this up with him.

The indirect things I can come up either sound passive-aggressive or might not be clear enough. An example of this might be something like "Hey, is there a reason that you don't use headphones when on a call?". I've also thought about making it about me: "I am pretty sensitive to loud noises and can get annoyed easy; do you think that you could make your calls quieter?" but this could be not direct or clear enough.

The more direct ways (e.g. "Can you find a way to be quieter on calls, especially after I go to bed?" or "Could you please use headphones instead of speakerphone?") seem fake or rude to me.

How do I suggest that he use headphones rather than be on speakerphone without running into either of those problems? Are either of the options I listed above better than I think? Or is there a better way? Is this better handled in person or over text?

Notes that may or not be relevant:

- I'm not sure if his clients actually disclose sensitive information over the phone, so that is not my main concern. If I only bring this up, a response like "they don't reveal any sensitive info" would be a good response but not address the problem.
- I say "roommate" but technically this is a property I own, so I am also the landlord.
- I'm very introverted and more sensitive to loud noises than anyone else I know, so I'll admit part of the problem is me. I really don't like when people play their music or stuff like that in public.
- I go to bed very early (usually around 8pm), so asking him to be quiet when I go to bed might be more difficult than with someone who goes to bed at a more "normal" hour

Comment: What part of your interaction with him do you think would potentially be 'condescending'? What's keeping you from just saying the things you wrote here, what about anything you wrote here would be 'condescending' in your opinion?

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Those are really good questions. I've tried editing my answer to be clearer about why I'm confused about what to say. Maybe I am just overthinking this though.

Comment: No worries. Apologies for the delay in responding, yesterday was chaotic for me. I've reopened this now, thanks for the edit!

Comment: What is fake or rude about writing a note to be read in private? "Can you find a way to be quieter on calls, especially after I go to bed?" or "Could you please use headphones instead of speakerphone?".